# Jquery dynamic image creation and animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, jquery-animate

I'm a bit confused. I've reviewed the jquery information on w3schools, but couldn't find anything about how to create/insert images using jquery. I've viewed several threads on here that seem to pertain to inserting an image dynamically but I can't even get the script to execute just the alert at the top, which makes me think that I've misdone the trigger somehow. If anyone could give me a bit of advice on how to fix what I've done, I'd appreciate it.

```
<script>
alert("Start");
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#krikri").hover(createGoat(){
    $("#krikri").append('<img src="images/goat.png" alt="animated goat" />');;
alert("End function 1");
    },trotting(){
    $("#krikri").animate({left:'250px'});
});}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling your functions correctly. The syntax is wrong here.

```
alert("Start");
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#krikri").hover(function() {
    $("#krikri").append('<img src="images/goat.png" alt="animated goat" />');;
    alert("End function 1");
    }, function(){
    $("#krikri").animate({left:'250px'});
  });
}
```

Comment: So "function" was actually supposed to be a keyword and not a placeholder?

Comment: Yes. Function is a keyword